# map pandas Dataframe columns to dictionary values

Tags: python, dictionary, pandas, dataframe

I have a one:many dictionary. I would like to map the values of a pandas Dataframe column to the keys (NOT values) of the dictionary. here is my dictionary:

```
dict1={'fruits':('apple','grapes','oranges'),'food':('fish','meat','fibre')}
```

And here is the pandas Series object:

```
df=pd.Series(['fish','apple','meat'])
```

the desired output i want:

```
0      food
1    fruits
2      food
dtype: object
```

Comment: You're going about this the wrong way. Your data structures are wrong. Dictionaries are meant for forward lookups, not reverse lookups. On top of that, you're doing a reverse lookup on a tuple, which means you have `O(n*m)` time complexity, where `n` is the number of keys in the dictionary and `m` is the average size of each tuple.

You should rather have a dictionary where each type of food is then mapped to a category, so `{'fish': 'food', 'appl'e:'fruits'}`, where your lookups have `O(1)` time complexity.

Comment: thanks for your comments, i will keep this in mind in future, i am new to coding.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

What if 'other' was in both 'fruits' and 'food'? That is why you cannot do a reverse lookup without having some sort of logic to resolve duplicates.

If your values are all unique, then you can reverse your dictionary using a dictionary comprehension:

```
reversed_dict = {val: key for key in dict1 for val in dict1[key]}

>>> reversed_dict
{'apple': 'fruits',
 'fibre': 'food',
 'fish': 'food',
 'grapes': 'fruits',
 'meat': 'food',
 'oranges': 'fruits'}
```

You could then map.

```
>>> pd.Series(['fish','apple','meat']).map(reversed_dict)
0      food
1    fruits
2      food
dtype: object
```

Comment: it works. I do get that: this is not the most optimal way to code and will redo my data structures. thanks for pointing that out.

Answer (score 1):

#### Solution

```
df.apply(lambda x: [k for k in dict1 if x in dict1[k]][0])
```